# How to get the report ID into my report in report studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a report studio report, in which I want to access the report id.

I know that report studio has the following function:

> ReportID()

However this returns a different ID every time the report is run, so it clearly isn't the ID of the report.

Is there a function that returns the actual report ID?